# Search in Windows Explorer display folder name in other language

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-explorer, language-packs

My computer was installed with Swedish operating system. I changed it to English.

In Windows Explorer i see C:\Users, but when i use the search function (in Windows Explorer)...it gives me C:\Användare (swedish for Users) in the result.

How do I get the search result in English?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was all about Indexing. When I turned off "Index searching", then it showed me C:\Users in the result.

http://ccm.net/faq/34613-windows-8-1-don-t-use-the-index-when-searching-in-files-folders-for-system-files

It's possible to Rebuild the Index, and that is a tip if you have changed language and want to keep Index when searching.